# How to get values from checkbox

Tags: javascript

here is my code. I can't make the alert works.

```
var chooseObject = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var objectLength = chooseObject.length;
var hobbyArray = [];
    //hobbyArray("aaa");
    //hobbyArray("bbb");
    //alert(hobbyArray); This one works.
for(var i=0;i<=objectLength;i++){
    if((chooseObject[i].type=="checkbox")&&(chooseObject[i].checked==true)){
         //alert(chooseObject[i].value); This one works.
         hobbyArray.push(chooseObject[i].value); }
}
alert(hobbyArray);
```

If I do the top alert(I comment already) it works. If I alert chooseObject[i].value in the for loop, its fine. But if I do with array, it failed. Could someone help me?

Comment: What do you expect to get with `alert(hobbyArray)`?

Comment: alerting an array is not exactly the way to go.. But most browser should give you some kind of content in your alert. Try `alert(hobbyArray.join(', '));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a silly error on your `for` statement. This:

```
for(var i=0;i<=objectLength;i++)
```

should be:

```
for(var i=0;i<objectLength;i++)
```

The extra iteration is causing a `TypeError` when you check the element's properties (`chooseObject[objectLength]` gives `undefined`, which has no properties).